# How do you add date range in .hta code?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, hta

I wrote an hta app that takes one search parameter.

With this search parameter, users can search by firstname, or lastname or both.

This works really well.

Today, management decided to add date range as part of the search.

I have tried to build the WHERE clause where a user can search with lastname, first name or both OR date range but not both.

In other words, on the one hand, users can search by lastname, first name or both using a form variable called txtsrch.

Or they can just use date range only using fromMDY as fromDate and toMDY as toDate.

So far, it isn't working out well.

Whether I enter a search into the name search box or I select a date range, I get type mismatch error.

I wasn't getting type mismatch error when it was just a searchbox only.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

This is minimal, I think relevant code.

Date is in the form of  1/1/2013

```vb
'*
Const cOPT = "<option value='?'>?</option>"
'*
Dim fromMDY(2)
Dim toMDY(2)
Dim optMDY(2)
optMDY(0) = "<option value='0'></option>"
optMDY(1) = "<option value='0'></option>"
optMDY(2) = "<option value='0'></option>"
Dim i
'*
For i = 1 To 12
  optMDY(0) = optMDY(0) & vbCrLf & Replace(cOPT,"?",i)
Next
For i = 1 To 31
  optMDY(1) = optMDY(1) & vbCrLf & Replace(cOPT,"?",i)
Next
For i = Year(Date)+1 To Year(Date)-4 Step -1
  optMDY(2) = optMDY(2) & vbCrLf & Replace(cOPT,"?",i)
Next

Sub Selected(What)
  Select Case What
  Case "FromMonth"
    fromMDY(0) = FromMonth.Value
  Case "FromDay"
    fromMDY(1) = FromDay.Value
  Case "FromYear"
    fromMDY(2) = FromYear.Value
  Case "ToMonth"
    toMDY(0) = ToMonth.Value
  Case "ToDay"
    toMDY(1) = ToDay.Value
  Case "ToYear"
    toMDY(2) = ToYear.Value
  End Select
End Sub

Sub DisplayDates()
  MsgBox "From:" & vbTab & Join(fromMDY,"/") & vbCrlf _
    & "To:" & vbTab & Join(toMDY,"/")
  End Sub

' first: Do we use AND or OR between clauses in the WHERE?
' AndOr = ANDOR.value
Sub radiocheck()
  for each b in ANDOR
    if b.checked Then AndOr = b.Value
  next
End Sub

' and now build up the WHERE:
where = ""

tsrch = txtsrch.Value

If tsrch <> "" Then
  where = where & " Name = '" & Replace(tsrch,"'","''") & "'"
End If

If fromMDY <> "" AND toMDY<> "" Then
    where = where & " convert(datetime, (left(dispdt,2)  + '/' + substring(dispdt,3,2) + '/' + case when cast(right(dispdt,2) as int) >= 70 then '19' else '20' end + right(dispdt,2)), 101) Between '"& fromMDY &"' AND '"& toMDY &"' "
End If


'Take care of sql injection tactics
SQL_query = "SELECT TOP 1000 Name, Rel, Estno, dtfild, pub, [TYPE OF DOCUMENT] typeofdocument, btyp, bkno, disp, dispdt, PGNO FROM PCS60418_MTHLY_XREF WHERE " _ 
  & where
msgBox sql_query
```

Comment: Hi @Cheran, I see that you edited my question - completely.

Thank you. May I know what you changed and why?

Thanks

Comment: you can click the time stamp above my name (e.g., "edited _21 hours ago_") to see the revision history. I just removed the greeting (which didn't add any value to the question) and added a language hint so that the syntax coloring would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is Case Insensitive. `ANDOR` is exactly the same as `AndOr` so if you are doing this:

```
Sub radiocheck()
    for each b in ANDOR
        if b.checked Then AndOr = b.Value
    next
End Sub
```

You are assigning a primitive to `AndOr` which conflicts with the `ANDOR` that is of type `Array` or `Iteratable Object`. Just rename one of the two variables and give it another try.

To prevent this kind of errors in the future: use `Option Explicit`, use correct (consistent) variable naming and use correct scoping: as locally as possible and passing variables to subroutines instead of using them as global variables.

Comment: thanks for your response.

Sorry I missed it this long. I appreciate the explanation but that's not the problem. Even after commenting this out, I still get the same error. It has to do with the "where"

Comment: I suggest you add the SQL tag to your question so SO-ers that are skilled in that area can see the question too. And add some of the queries that are assembled by your HTA that won't work. Not everybody who know their SQLs are also capable of (or willing to) read(ing) the VBScript in your post.